# Bitwig: Get specific clip in independent of selection

Tags: clip, bitwig

I want to get a clip object independent of the currently selected object in the mixer view.

I can only get a clipLauncherSlotBank via

`host.createTrackBank(1, 0, 1).getItemAt(0).clipLauncherSlotBank()`

but not the clip.

I can also get a pinnableCursorClip via

`host.createCursorTrack("8dbcc337-9a41-4ab5-9dd9-97cd74c3437f", "Test", 0, 1, false).createLauncherCursorClip(16, 128)`

but how can I then set the cursorTrack to a specific track and/or the pinnableCursorClip to a specific clip?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Override
public void init() {
  ControllerHost host = getHost();
  host.getMidiInPort(0).setMidiCallback((ShortMidiMessageReceivedCallback) this::onMidi0);

  int trackIndex = 6;
  int sceneIndex = 0;
  TrackBank trackBank = host.createTrackBank(trackIndex + 1, 0, sceneIndex + 1);
  Track track = trackBank.getItemAt(trackIndex);
  ClipLauncherSlotBank clipLauncherSlotBank = track.clipLauncherSlotBank();
  ClipLauncherSlot clipLauncherSlot = clipLauncherSlotBank.getItemAt(sceneIndex);
  clipLauncherSlot.select();
  CursorTrack cursorTrack = host.createCursorTrack("8dbcc337-9a41-4ab5-9dd9-97cd74c3437f", "Test", 0, sceneIndex + 1, false);
  this.pinnableCursorClip = cursorTrack.createLauncherCursorClip(16, 128);

  host.scheduleTask(() -> {
     cursorTrack.isPinned().set(true);
     pinnableCursorClip.isPinned().set(true);
  }, 1000);
}

public void onMidi0(ShortMidiMessage msg) {
  pinnableCursorClip.setStep(0, 0, 127, 0.125);
}
```